# Can't install htmlhelp.exe (HTML Help Workshop) because of error on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, setup, chm

When I download HTML Help Workshop from Microsoft, the first part is a success, but after 2 boxes this appears:

> Error creating process
>
> C:\Users\AWAKE_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP000.TIMP\setup.exe
>
> Reason: The requested operation requires elevation.

What do I do to fix this and what caused it?

By the way, I have a 64-bit operating system and a x64-based processor. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Elevation" means that the process should be run as Administrator. You could try right-clicking on the installation file and select "Run as administrator"